How to find inputs of a specific type with Umbrella.js?
How do I find all the siblings of an element which are input tags of a given type?
I'm trying to find all the hidden inputs that are siblings of a specific checkbox.

Provided that you have the filter to find the element el whose siblings you'd like to find, this expression will find all input elements of hidden type:
u(el).siblings('input[type=hidden]')

